# How to pass array dynamically in asyncBlurField redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am following redux form tutorial and almost done with that but could not pass the array in asyncValidate file

I need to change array `['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']` with the array coming from server response...

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const asyncValidate = (values /*, dispatch */) => {
  return sleep(1000).then(() => {
    // simulate server latency
    if (['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.username)) {
      throw { username: 'That username is taken' }
    }
  })
}

export default asyncValidate
```

Answer (score 1):

your `asyncValidate` function needs to make an api call that returns you the list like

```
const asyncValidate = (values /*, dispatch */) => {
  return axios.get('url').then((data) => {
    if (data.includes(values.username)) {
      throw { username: 'That username is taken' }
    }
  })
}

export default asyncValidate
```

Comment: If you pass it to the validate function, it no longer is an async validate, rather just validate.

Comment: I still could not find the correct way to implement async blur fields in redux form... can you please help me to do it...